# Custom IdentifierGenerator

Tags: junit, spring-data, hsqldb

I am currently facing a problem that makes me crazy.

I would like to create my own IdentifierGenerator to manage ids with a specific format.

```
public class CustomGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    private static final String REQUEST = "SELECT CURRVAL('sequence')";

    private final String prefixFormat = "PREFIX-%s";

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        final String prefix = getPrefix();
        Session sessionHibernate = (Session) session;
        Query query = sessionHibernate.createSQLQuery(REQUEST );
        Object obj = query.uniqueResult();
        return null;
    }

    private String getPrefix() {
        final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
        return String.format(prefixFormat, dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
    }

}
```

My Junit Test:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void addEntity() {
    final Entity entity= new Entity();
    final long count = this.entityRepository.count();

    this.entityRepository.saveAndFlush(rex);

    assertEquals(count + 1, this.entityRepository.count());
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence", strategy = "[...]CustomGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence")
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID")
    private Integer entityId;

    [...]
}
```

My JUnit test crashes  - Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not  prepare statement; SQL [SELECT CURRVAL('sequence_rex_id')]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:238)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
```

Database: HSQLDB (test), POSTGRESQL (production)

Does anyone have any idea ?

Sorry for any mistakes I could have made. English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: I moved tests from HSQLDB to POSTGRESQL and the problem disappeared.

I suppose the problem comes from the configuration of HSQLDB(2.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT CURRVAL('sequence')` syntax is specific to PostgreSQL. When using PostgreSQL syntax in HSQLDB, you should include the necessary SQL syntax flag in the JDBC connection URL. For example `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true`

Comment: It does not solve the problem, I still have the same error !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nextval` not `CURRVAL`.

Is

> Returns the value most recently obtained **by nextval** for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported **if nextval has never been called for this sequence in this session.**)
> (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)